# I want to make array elements as a object with dynamic allocation but segmentaion error found. c++

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

i want to make array elements as object and making the copy of class of each element and store the data in member variable i am using pointer and new keyword in this code to use minimum space in this code.c plus plus is the programming language(c++)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>           //ERROR is segmentation fault;
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
int value,fix;
int *ptr=&value;
class product{
    string name;
    public:
    void add(){
        cout<<"product name"<<endl;
        cin>>name;
    }
};
int main(){
    cout<<"how many products coustomer buy"<<endl;
    cin>>*ptr; //save the first input value
    fix=*ptr;  //fix using in loop
    ptr=new int[value]; //dynamic allocation ,making array 
    for(int i=0;i<fix;i++){ 
        cout<<"enter number of product"<<endl;
        cin>>ptr[i];
        product ptr[i]; //make array a object
        ptr[i].add(); //access the method of class
        cout<<"_________________________"<<endl;
    }
    // this is the show array
    for(int i=0;i<fix;i++){
        cout<<ptr[i]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code snippet

```
ptr=new int[value]; //dynamic allocation ,making array 
for(int i=0;i<fix;i++){ 
    cout<<"enter number of product"<<endl;
    cin>>ptr[i];
    product ptr[i]; //make array a object
    ptr[i].add(); //access the method of class
    cout<<"_________________________"<<endl;
}
```

does not make sense.

At first you allocated an array of integers

```
ptr=new int[value]; //dynamic allocation ,making array
```

Then within the for loop you entered a value for the i-th element of the array

```
    cin>>ptr[i];
```

And then you redeclared the name `ptr` as a variable length array (variable length arrays are not a standard C++ feature) of elements of the type `product`

```
    product ptr[i]; //make array a object
```

Moreover in the first iteration of the for loop the array is defined with `0` elements because in the first iteration of the loop `i` is equal to `0`. So this results in undefined behavior. And the life -time of the declared arrays in the for loop is the compound statement of the for loop. Outside the for loop the arrays will not be alive.

If you want to have an array of elements of the type `product` then you need to allocate it dynamically before the for loop the same way as you allocated the array of integers in this statement before the for loop

```
ptr=new int[value]; //dynamic allocation ,making array
```

Actually the array of integers is not required in the program. It is enough to allocate dynamically an array of objects of the type `product` though it will be much better to use standard container `std::vector`.

Comment: when i input the elements in this array using this pointer method and fetch array all elements show in console and  it work but the trouble is when i will make the array elements a class object it will give me segmentation fault

Comment: @vivekrai What is unclear in my answer? This line product ptr[i]; is invalid. Is it clear?